# ¿Cómo instalo una copia en local de un sitio WordPress que está en producción?

Tags: php, wordpress

Estoy haciendo una copia de un sitio WordPress para trabajar en local:

Exporté la base de datos desde phpmyadmin y descargué todos los archivos de la web usando filezilla. Intenté utilizar plugins para ésta tarea pero no pude utilizar ninguno, todos me daban error. Probé WP migrate DB, all in one wp migration, duplicator y otros, pero todos terminaban en error así que decidí hacerlo manualmente. Entonces, una vez descargados todos los datos desde el servidor, hice los cambios respectivos en la base de datos (en wp_options.siteurl, y otras tres tablas donde coloqué la URL del proyecto en mi servidor local ["localhost/TVE"]).
Estoy utilizando un entorno LAMP, con Apache, php7 y mysql.
Uso ubuntu 16.04.

Según la mayoría de los tutoriales que he leído, ya con éstos pasos realizados debería poder acceder al dashboard de wordpress y hacer un ajuste en los permalinks para visualizar el sitio, pero no puedo ingresar ni al dashboard, ni al sitio.

Por cierto, como observacion, cada vez que introduzco "localhost/tve" en el navegador, se agrega automaticamente un HTTPS:// al principio. No sé si ésto tenga algo que ver, yo no sé si https funciona o no en local, no sé sobre el tema.

He intentado muchas otras cosas pero no consigo hacerlo funcionar, me pueden ayudar porfavor?

Les dejo el archivo htacces y la salida en el navegador

```html
# BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

# END WordPress

# BEGIN LiteSpeed
    <IfModule Litespeed>
    SetEnv noabort 1
    </IfModule>
# END LiteSpeed
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y levantaste alguna clase de servidor web sobre donde poner el wordpress para que funcione?

Comment: claro. Utilizo apache sobre ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Perfecto. Agrega esa info a la pregunta. Quiero creer que instalaste php tambien no?

Comment: porsupuesto. Ya la edito. Gracias por la observacion

Comment: Tienes que correr un "search" and "replace" en todas las tablas de la base de datos para cambiar el nombre de host ya que WP lo usa para el funcionamiento. En mi caso, he exportado las tablas en formato SQL, he hecho el reemplazo con un editor tipo notepad++ en los archivos y luego importar en el nuevo host y ha funcionado sin problemas. También se puede hacer con query si ya está importada la BD.

Comment: si, lo hice. Coloqué "Localhost/tve" que es la direccion donde tengo la carpeta con los archivos de la web de producción

Comment: ¿El servidor local está publicando por https? (puerto 443)

Comment: no sé porque se agrega HTTPS al principio. Yo no he configurado nada de HTTPS en localhost, ni se como funciona HTTPS en localhost

Answer (score 0):

creo que la solución esta en la configuración dentro de la base de datos, ¿podrás poner la tabla options? Otra cosa que podes probar es cambiar el nombre a la carpeta PLUGINS así no los usa y descartas algún problema ahí.

Comment: si, ya edité la tabla options y otras tablas que necesitaban el mismo cambio de la URL. Lo extraño es que todo el procedimiento que hice me funcionó en windows, pero en ubuntu no. Que será lo que me falta?